# Regex - regular expression to extract value from inconsistent string

Tags: regex

I have a group of strings and need to extract a specific part out of them. The problem is, the placement of the parameter I need to pull varies throughout - sometimes at the start, other times in the middle, etc.

Here are some examples, where I want to extract the part beginning with `RSC` (not `PCRSC`):

```
RSC198343_PCRSC247_5149_30636
PCRSC758_RSC847295_3602_58406
```

I've tried with this expression:

```
([^PC]RSC.*?)_
```

But it won't work when the string starts with `RSC` - only in the case where it starts `PCRSC`. Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use negative lookbehind

```
(?<!PC)(RSC.*?)_
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lP2hS1/2)